# SQL - summing multiple rows with same IDs in different tables

Tags: sqlite

I have 3 tables:

```
A:
ID | col1 | col2 | have
1  |  x   |   x  |  2
2  |  x   |   y  |  3

B:
ID | col1 | have
1  |  x   |  1
1  |  x   |  5

C:
ID | have
3  | 8
2  | 5
1  | 2
```

ID is not a primary key, just a foreign key.

I have trouble writing a query which will sum all of them. This is my work and I'm unsure on why it's not working:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(have)
    FROM (
        SELECT ID, SUM(have) AS have
            FROM A
            GROUP BY ID
        UNION
        SELECT ID, SUM(have) AS have
            FROM B
            GROUP BY ID
        SELECT ID, SUM(have) AS have
            FROM C
            GROUP BY ID
    )
    GROUP BY ID
```

I'm using sqlite3 in python, but I doubt it would make any difference as this is quite basic SQL query - hence the fault is in data or my query (guessing the latter).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, SUM(have)
FROM (
    SELECT ID, SUM(have) AS have
        FROM A
        GROUP BY ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, SUM(have) AS have
        FROM B
        GROUP BY ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, SUM(have) AS have
        FROM C
        GROUP BY ID
)
GROUP BY ID
```

try this, when you use UNION it only unites unique results by using UNION ALL you incorporate all of the result, you have to do this for all of the SUM's you are uniting.

Comment: I will give it a try, but I assume that is correct, what a silly mistake >.>